# Does anyone know where the third easter egg in Nintendo Nightmare is at?

Tags: nintendo-nightmare

I've been playing Nintendo Nightmare for a while and I am stuck in the post-ending stuff. I've found the first two easter eggs (the one when you kill the first supposedly 'unkillable' boss, and the one behind the entrance to the Eggman boss). Does anybody know where this might be at. I know this is a sort of niche question, but I figure somebody here might know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the third and final easter egg by "killing" the final boss with a cheat, actually destroying its object instance in the room.

> You can get to the final boss quickly by typing this cheat: `room_goto(229)`
>
>  Once inside the boss room, type this command in the cheat textbox:
>  `with(obj_chucknorris) instance_destroy()`
>
>  This will destroy all instances (in this case, one) of obj_chucknorris in the room, then the game will display the final easter egg text.
>
>  [image: Picture showing the third easter egg from Nintendo Nightmare]

Comment: Wow. I would've never thought this would actually work. Im gonna go test it. If it does it would be pretty funny seeing as how the ending references that cheat as the only way to do that. Clever indeed. :)

Comment: I have tested and confirmed the validity of this answer. Btw, how did you manage to find this? I've been searching for a very long time.

Comment: Well, the ending did gave me a clue, when it said something like "if you beat Chuck Norris, you must be actually cheating". ;)
So I remembered the cheat/programming codes in the game, and I tried destroying the boss that way, and it worked! Hehe.

Comment: I've had also seen a clue in [this walkthrough](http://one.denizenscript.com/yygf/classic/5/topics/26039.html), that pointed me to the right direction:
"Easter Egg 3 - It is somewhere that is only accessible after the Death Egg is beat." (The final boss area really is only accessible after the Death Egg!)

Comment: Ah nostalgia. Btw, who do you think made that post, lol? I'm actually shocked that site is still up. I heard that archive was being removed. XD

Comment: Wow, until now, I thought who made that post was supmaster004, the game's developer, but only now I'd seen that another user discovered and posted the easter eggs clues... That's what happens when I'm not paying attention. 'o' Maybe that user is some friend of the dev, or a tester for the game... And I already made sure to save that page before someone removes it! xD

Comment: lol man. I was covertly saying *I* made that post a looong time ago, but I guess it went over your hear. Glad it ended up helping you, man! And nah. That was years after it was made. I just commented there asking for help. Not even the dev could find it (and trust me he said he looked). I guess we were all looking for signs and not random dialogue.

Comment: Oooh yeah, now I got it! xD Really, thank you for making that post, it sure helped me! :) I was also looking for a third sign, but then I had a hunch about "cheating to defeat Chuck Norris", hehe. I thought that maybe a sign would appear where he was standing, similarly to the first easter egg. (and that's also a nice bookend to the easter eggs, there being secrets at the first and the final boss!)

Comment: Well, and the ironic bit too is that when I first played the game, after finishing I randomly spawned in a bunch of enemies and bosses in spawn (including several non-clones chuck norris) and yet I never destroyed any of the indexes. Honestly, I'm glad I know this thing now, though. I was planning on rebuilding some of the levels with a massive cheat and it would pretty annoying to have this start happening as a "bug". At least this also helps me in that avenue as well. XD